# 2 questions about datagridviews: text in button and columns disapearing

Tags: c#, unicode, datagridview

1. Whenever I try to set the value of buttons in my DataGridView button column with this character "►", the generator genrate them with "[]".

2.When I try to switch column using the "modify columns" options of the DataGridView... All my columns disapear. When I press ctrl+z, I lose the last column.

I'm using VS2010

Any help will be apreciated! :)

Comment: for the first question, I cannot understand why you can have "[]" or "►". for the second question, the situation really weird and how come you can undo with CRTL Z even not fully undo....May be you need include the version of your Microsoft Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the character in the DGV: some font doesn't have this character

For the column lost : Programming environnement not set up as it should be.(And a bug in VS 2010)